# is this the right way to use cbw in Mul?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, sign-extension

I get the Multiplication from 8bit and 8bit register. But, when you have one in 16 bit, and one in 8bit, how do we do the conversion before multiplying:

Question : need to provide code fragments for 260*19, and print the results. I did:

```
mov Ax,260
mov Al,19
cbw;
Mul Ax 
PutInt Ax
```

Comment: no, `cbw` sign-extends AL into AX, overwriting your other input.  Use a debugger.  Take your 16-bit input in a different register, like DX (which will be overwritten by the high-half output of 16-bit `mul`).  Or extend at assemble time, like `mov cx, 19` / `mul cx`

Comment: BTW, there's nothing special about MUL here, except that it and CBW both implicitly use AX.  Normally you use CBW / CWD / CDQ as setup for `div`: [When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36464879).  But sure, if you have a number in AL you want to sign-extend, then CBW is the most efficient way, and MUL does need both inputs to be the same width.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov Ax,260
> mov Al,19
> ```

The `AL` register is the lowest half of the `AX` register.

```
            AX
    /-----------------\
MSB xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx LSB
    \-------/ \-------/
        AH        AL
```

The 2nd instruction `mov al, 19` thus erroneously overwrites your 1st number.

> ```
> Mul Ax
> ```

The byte-sized `mul` instruction multiplies the `AL`register by the specified byte-sized operand.
The word-sized `mul` instruction multiplies the `AX`register by the specified word-sized operand.

Using `mul ax` then would calculate `AX * AX`, which is not what you wanted. You want to multiply different numbers.

Using `AX` together with another register like `BX` solves both problems.

---

What to do with that `cbw` depends on how we look at the code.

- If you work with the numbers as immediates (260, 19), then just use a word-sized register even for the small number 19:

  ```
  mov     bx, 260
  mov     ax, 19
  mul     bx       ; Product AX * BX is in DX:AX but here DX=0
  PutInt  ax
  ```

  or even let the assembler do the multiplication:

  ```
  mov     ax, 260 * 19
  PutInt  ax
  ```
- If the numbers come from memory (different sized variables) then you need to extend the smaller one.

  - Unsigned numbers, use `mul`for **unsigned** multiply

    ```
    mov     bx, wNum  ; [0,65535]
    mov     al, bNum  ; [0,255]
    mov     ah, 0
    mul     bx        ; Product AX * BX is in DX:AX
    PutInt  ax
    ```

    I advice against using `cbw` in this case! Using `cbw` would criple all numbers from 128 upwards.
  - Signed numbers, use `imul`for **signed** multiply

    ```
    mov     bx, wNum  ; [-32768,32767]
    mov     al, bNum  ; [-128,127]
    cbw
    imul    bx        ; Product AX * BX is in DX:AX
    PutInt  ax
    ```

    `cbw` is the right choice to extend the signed byte from `AL`.