# Why am I getting an unexpected value from mul with a memory variable?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am using this call to test a question in my assignment. I am new to assembly language.

```
INCLUDE PCMAC.INC
       .MODEL SMALL
       .586
       .STACK 100H
.DATA
lfc     DW  1892
ger DB  8

.CODE
EXTRN GetDec:Near,PutDec:Near
start       PROC
            _Begin
            mov ax, lfc
            mul ger
            call PutDec
            _Exit 0

start       ENDP 
            END start
```

I am expecting PutDec to display 15136, but my output is 800. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Recall that this `mul` is a byte-sized multiplication because `ger` is a byte-sized operand.  It'll multiply `AL` with `get` producing output in `AX`.  The contents of `AH` are ignored.

Comment: I see now! Thanks, changing `ger` to `DB` solved the issue.

Comment: Is this 32-bit code (`.586`)?  If so, PutDec probably expects a value in the full EAX, and MUL writing AL leaves the upper half unmodified (and thus possibly holding garbage)

Comment: Near duplicate: [is this the right way to use cbw in Mul?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55645909)